# Recode NA when another column value is NA in R

Tags: r, recode

I have a quick recoding question. Here is my sample dataset looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                 i1 = c(1,NA,0),
                 i2 = c(1,1,1))

> df
  id i1 i2
1  1  1  1
2  2 NA  1
3  3  0  1
```

When, `i1==NA` , then I need to recode `i2==NA`. I tried below but not luck.

```
df %>%
  mutate(i2 = case_when(
    i1 == NA ~  NA_real_,
    TRUE ~ as.character(i2)))

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `i2 = case_when(i1 == "NA" ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ as.character(i2))`.
Caused by error in `` names(message) <- `*vtmp*` ``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

my desired output looks like this:

```
> df
  id i1 i2
1  1  1  1
2  2 NA  NA
3  3  0  1
```

Comment: `NA_real_` is an NA that is encoded as a numeric. You probably want `as.numeric(i2)` or just `i2` where you have `as.character(i2)`, so that the output type can be consistent for each `case_when` possibility.

Comment: don't use `i1 == NA` use `is.na(i1)`

Comment: Agreed. The result of an operation containing a missing value is missing. So `i1 == NA` is not TRUE when `i1` is missing, it is NA. For example, try `NA == NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a simple assignment meet your requirements for this?

`df$i2[is.na(df$i1)] <- NA`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option:

```r
t(apply(df, 1, \(x) if (any(is.na(x))) cumsum(x) else x))
#     id i1 i2
#[1,]  1  1  1
#[2,]  2 NA NA
#[3,]  3  0  1
```

The idea is to calculate the cumulative sum of every row, if a row contains an `NA`; if there is an `NA` in term *i* , subsequent terms *i+1* will also be `NA` (since e.g. `NA + 1 = NA`). Since your sample data `df` is all numeric, I recommend using a `matrix` (rather than a `data.frame`). Matrix operations are usually faster than `data.frame` (i.e. `list`) operations.

Key assumptions:

1. `id` cannot be `NA`.
2. This replaces `NA`s in `i2` based on an `NA` in `i1` **per row**.

---

### A `tidyverse` solution

I advise against a `tidyverse` solution here for a couple of reasons

1. Your data is all-numerical, so a `matrix` is a more suitable data structure than a `data.frame`/`tibble`.
2. `dplyr`/`tidyr` syntax usually operates efficiently on columns; as soon as you want to do things "row-wise", `dplyr` (and its family packages) might not be the best way (despite `dplyr::rowwise()` which just introduces a row number-based grouping).

With that out of the way, you can `transpose` the problem.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    transpose() %>%
    map(~ { if (is.na(.x$i1)) .x$i2 <- NA_real_; .x }) %>%
    transpose() %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    unnest(everything())
## A tibble: 3 × 3
#     id    i1    i2
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1
#2     2    NA    NA
#3     3     0     1
```